# How to get the difference between the first two records for each unique record in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.4

I have a table:

```
   evt_type | value      | time
  ------------+------------+--------------------
   2          | 5          | 2015-05-09 12:42:00
   4          | -42        | 2015-05-09 13:19:57
   2          | 2          | 2015-05-09 14:48:30
   2          | 7          | 2015-05-09 12:54:39
   3          | 16         | 2015-05-09 13:19:57
   3          | 20         | 2015-05-09 15:01:09
```

And I want to get the difference (in the value column) between the latest and second latest evt_type (for each evt_type that has two or more entries).

I've written a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE event_type IN (
    SELECT event_type
    FROM events
    GROUP BY event_type
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
)
ORDER BY event_type ASC, time DESC
```

that returns the following results:

```
 evt_type   value   time
+----------+------+---------------------+
| 2        |  2   | 2015-05-09 14:48:30 |
| 2        |  7   | 2015-05-09 12:54:39 |
| 2        |  5   | 2015-05-09 12:42:00 |
| 3        | 20   | 2015-05-09 15:01:09 |
| 3        | 16   | 2015-05-09 13:19:57 |
+----------+------+---------------------+
```

How do I get the difference in the value column for the first two rows of each unique `evt_type`? Can I get the difference using this query as a sub-query? Or do I need to use another approach?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: `LEAD` and `LAG`.

Answer (score 2):

Use "window functions" for this, here the `LEAD` is used to bring the earlier dated value into the current row so that the difference can be calculated. `ROW_NUMBER` is used so we can filter out rows we are not interested in. Here because you ar focussed on just the latest -v- second latest values, we really only need "the most recent" row (rn = 1) in the final result.

```
select
       evt_type
     , value
     , prev_val
     , value - prev_val as value_diff
     , time
     , rn   
from (
  select 
         *
       , row_number() over(partition by evt_type order by time DESC) as rn
       , lead(value,1) over(partition by evt_type order by time DESC) as prev_val
  from events
  ) as d
where rn = 1
```

**nb:** the order specified in the `over` clause is descending, so `LEAD` in this case is looking back in time.

| evt_type | value | prev_val | value_diff | time | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 7 | -5 | 2015-05-09 14:48:30 | 1 |
| 3 | 20 | 16 | 4 | 2015-05-09 15:01:09 | 1 |
| 4 | -42 | *null* | *null* | 2015-05-09 13:19:57 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aMXBOE9Q)

Comment: Thanks @Paul Maxwell. I was able to use your solution to get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this query

```
WITH ranked_data AS (
        SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY evt_type ORDER BY time DESC) AS ranking
        FROM events
    )

SELECT *, (r1.value - r2.value) AS difference  
FROM ranked_data r1
     LEFT JOIN ranked_data r2 
       ON r1.evt_type = r2.evt_type AND 
          r1.ranking = 1 AND r2.ranking = 2
WHERE r1.ranking = 1;
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/1roHj5wk)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Paul Maxwell's answer, I was able to get the data I wanted by using his query as a subquery:

```
WITH sub_query as (
    SELECT *
    FROM events
    WHERE evt_type IN (
        SELECT evt_type
        FROM events
        GROUP BY evt_type
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
    )
    ORDER BY evt_type ASC, time DESC
)

select evt_type, value_diff
from 
(select
    evt_type, 
    value, 
    prev_val, 
    value - prev_val as value_diff, 
    time, 
    rn   
from (
  select 
        *, 
        row_number() over(partition by evt_type order by time DESC) as rn,
        lead(value,1) over(partition by evt_type order by time DESC) as prev_val
  from sub_query
  ) as d
where rn = 1) as sub_query_2
```

To get the result:

| evt_type | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | -5 |
| 3 | 4 |